# Alignment of Member Array in Class not Working

Tags: c++, alignment, member, alignas

I use the following to 16-byte align a 4 element float array in a class

```cpp
class Foo
{
    // ... some code

    private:
    alignas(16) float array[4];
};
```

The variable is not aligned. Why is that? My assumption would be that the alignment depends on the alignment of the instance of `Foo` since the internal offset of member variables is static and not adjusted on runtime. Is that correct or am I missing something? Thus one thing to fix it would be to align Foo with something `>=16` so that the internal offsets are fixed?

Comment: how do you know that it is not aligned? What do you mean exactly when you say "The variable is not aligned." ?

Comment: `alignas(16) float array[4];` should work.  Can you show us a [mre] that doesn't?

Comment: OK,then my assumption already seems to be wrong. I can't give you a minimal example. I'll try to create one but I assume it'll simply work if that's what it's supposed to do. 

After construction of Foo, array is pointing to a 8 byte aligned address, the last hex-digit is 8 instead of 0.

Comment: Foo is created dynamically with new, if that is important for this example.

Comment: Ok,  `alignof(std::max_align_t);` returns 8. That afaik means that the compiler doesn't guarantee that alignment over 8 bytes (in dynamic allocations?) is supported.

Comment: Is there any conclusion here? I also confused in this issue that array somehow aligns to 8 even if I specify the alignment explicitly like what ruhig did.